# MInimize internet bandwidth usage

Tags: networking

I am traveling and using a 3G mobile internet provider, it has limit of 3GB download every 7 days. So I was wondering what tweaks can I apply in Ubuntu 12.04.3 to minimize internet usage. I already disabled flash and images on my browser, but what else could I do. Are there some programs that use bandwidth on the background I can disable or any other tips?

Comment: I specially cannot point out any apps or a command which would help.. not that I know of..

Comment: I think marking the question as duplicated is incorrect, the other question as to monitor or limit bandwidth, I ask about programs that may be using bandwidth without my knowledge and such.

Comment: Yes, this is wrongly closed as this is not a dupe of that question. But I found another question for which this is a dupe, here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91736/reduce-network-traffic-disable-update-manager-and-so-on The accepted answer there has a nice solution. I think you should check it out.  Unfortunately the poster of that answer didn't write his answer there, just give a link to the solution.

Comment: To know which programs may use your bandwidth you need "to monitor" them, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Turning off flash and images was a good idea. You may also want to check out a text-only browser like lynx or elinks.
- Turn off automatic updates and checks for automatic updates:

  Open Software Center, navigate to *Edit->Software Sources...*. On the *Updates* tab change *Automatically check for updates* to *Never*.
- Disable all syncing services you have (Ubuntu One, Dropbox, etc.).